# What impact does my character's nationality have in Wasteland?

Tags: wasteland

When creating a character in *Wasteland*, you are prompted to choose your nationality.

[image: Wasteland 1 nationality screen]

What impact does this have on gameplay? I couldn't figure out if it mattered.

Comment: [The wiki says there is no effect](http://wasteland.gamepedia.com/Character_creation) for nationality, and gender just affects dialog options. I've only played the 2nd one though, so i hesitate to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nationality has no effect. Only Gender matters, and only in one place that I can think of.